# Intuition behind the entropy functional for curvature bounds

Tags: riemannian-geometry, entropy, geometric-measure-theory, functional-inequalities, optimal-transport

What is the intuition behind defining in metric measure spaces a Ricci curvature bound via convexity or concavity of the entropy functional? I know that this is made because in Riemannian manifolds the Ricci curvature bounds can be characterized via these inequalities, but in every paper that result seems to come "from above", without explaining why precisely the entropy encodes that.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you're looking for, but one way to see that Ricci curvature bounds can be formulated in terms of convexity properties of the entropy is to note that the Hessian of the entropy in Wasserstein space is given in terms of the $\Gamma_2$-operator. This connects semi-convexity of the entropy to Bakry-Émery's $\Gamma_2$-condition. Of course this justification is still very much on the technical side.

Comment: Can you provide me with some references about that? I'm studying it but get intuitions is difficult

Comment: The computation of the Hessian is done in Villani's second book on optimal transport, which is probably the best textbook on the topic until Sturm's book comes out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not intending rigour here, but probably it helps to get some intuition. On a Hilbert space or manifold, consider the gradient flow $\dot{\xi}=-\nabla f(\xi)$. Then the strong $k$- convexity of the potential $f$ is equivalent to exponentially fast contraction of flow trajectories, i.e. $d(\xi^{x}(t),\xi^{y}(t))\le e^{-kt}d(x,y)$ with $x,y$ being initial states of two flows.
Now on the other hand, one of the various equivalent ways to characterize lower Ricci curvature bounds is by requiring heat to contract exponentially fast (e.g. by means of Brownian motion trajectories). Physical reasoning behind would be that without global lower bounds, you may find initial starting points, close to singularities in your manifold, where trajectories may not contract at all.
Now where is the entropy? Since the seminal work of Felix Otto (c.f. 'THE GEOMETRY OF DISSIPATIVE EVOLUTION EQUATIONS: THE POROUS MEDIUM EQUATION'), we know that the heat equation can itself be interpreted as Wasserstein gradient flow, for which the driving functional is precisely the Boltzmann entropy, i.e. $\dot{\mu}=-\nabla^{W}\operatorname{Ent}(\mu)$. Therefore, (recall first paragraph) strong convexity of the entropy is equivalent to exponential contraction of heat flow is equivalent to lower Ricci curvature bound.
This observation goes back originally to von Renesse & Sturm 'Transport inequalities, Gradient Estimates, Entropy and Ricci Curvature'.